# What does overflowing mean in this case?

Tags: c++, pseudocode, assertion

I have found an algorithm to multiply in modoulus. The next pseudocode is taken from wikipedia, page Modular exponention, section Right-to-left binary method.

The full pseudocode is

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
    Assert :: (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) does not overflow base
    result := 1
    base := base mod modulus
    while exponent > 0
        if (exponent mod 2 == 1):
           result := (result * base) mod modulus
        exponent := exponent >> 1
        base := (base * base) mod modulus
    return result
```

I don't understand what this line of pseudocode means `Assert :: (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) does not overflow base`; what does this line mean and how would it be best programmed in C++?

Answer (score 2):

In most computer programming languages numbers can only be stored with a limited precision or over a certain range.

For example a C++ integer will often be a 32 bit signed int, capable of storing at most 2^31 as a value.

If you try and multiply together two numbers and the result would be greater than 2^31 you do not get the result you were expecting, it has overflowed.

Comment: if i understand correctly you are trying to say that that line of code means that (modulus-1)^2 should be less than 2^31 (for signed int). Is it right?

Comment: Essentially yes. You need to look at the overflow limits for the data type you are using and then check you are not going to exceed them.

Answer (score 1):

`Assert` is (roughly speaking) a way to check preconditions; "this must be true to proceed". In C++ you'll code it using the [`assert` macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), or your own hand-rolled assertion system.

'does not overflow' means that the statement shouldn't be too large to fit into whatever integer type `base` is; it's a multiplication so it's quite possible. Integer overflow in C++ is undefined behaviour, so it's wise to guard against it! There are plenty of resources out there to explain integer overflow, such as [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

To do the check in C++, a nice simple approach is to store the intermediate result in a larger integer type and check that it's small enough to fit in the destination type. For example, if `base` is `int32_t` use `int64_t` and check that it's lower than `static_cast<int64_t>(std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max())`:

```
const int64_t intermediate = (static_cast<int64_t>(modulus) - 1) * (static_cast<int64_t>(modulus) - 1);
assert(intermediate < static_cast<int64_t>(std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max()));
```

Comment: I could test it in another way which I think is better. Please fell free to correct me if I am wrong. If i use int64_t for all my variables, I can get the sqrt of INT64_MAX constant's value and than see if is bigger than modulus-1.

Comment: @CPJ: (modulus-1) <= INT64_MAX/(modulus-1) => no overflow

Comment: @DieterLücking however, that would mean that always it will make the / operation. While the sqrt could be done only once and than create a new #define with that value and always use it to compare. Anyways, yours is a great observation which I must say I didn't think of; thank You.

Comment: Dieter's suggestion is a good one, and less prone to error than mine (I just noticed that the calculation of `intermediate` would overflow before getting assigned to an `int64_t`! Fixed.). For more complex statements though, it may not be obvious how to write the check that way.