# What does it mean to not overflow in this psuedocode: Assert :: (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) does not overflow base

Tags: python, overflow, pseudocode, pow

I have pseudocode that has an assert like this:

`Assert :: (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) does not overflow base`

I interpreted this as:

`assert (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) < base`

I don't think this is correct, so what does the overflow actually mean?

This is pseudocode to the pow(x,y,z) function in python.
Here is the full pseudocode:

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus) is
    if modulus = 1 then
        return 0
    Assert :: (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) does not overflow base
    result := 1
    base := base mod modulus
    while exponent > 0 do
        if (exponent mod 2 == 1) then
            result := (result * base) mod modulus
        exponent := exponent >> 1
        base := (base * base) mod modulus
    return result
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I found the answer to this problem. Overflow refers to integer overflow. In this case, it is referring to the largest 32-bit signed integer, which is (1 << 31) - 1, or 2147483647. In python, I wrote this as:

```
assert (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) <= ((1 << 31) - 1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175086/what-does-overflowing-mean-in-this-case
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528637/checking-integer-overflow-in-python